# Evaluate 2D trigonometric integration of $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)^3}{\cos(x)-\cos(y)}dydx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals, singular-integrals

I have the following example of an integral:

$$ I = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 x}{\cos x - \cos y} \ dy \ dx $$

I can determine the exact value of this integral by leveraging the symmetry properties of integrals:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 x}{\cos x - \cos y} dy dx + \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 y}{\cos y - \cos x} dx dy\right) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 x - \cos^3 y}{\cos x - \cos y} dy dx\right) $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^2 x + \cos^2 y + \cos x\cos y) dy dx\right) = \frac{1}{2} $$

In my case, I need to evaluate the first integral with respect to $y$:

$$ I(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos x - \cos y} dy $$

and then integrate over $x$:

$$ I = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}I(x)\cos^3 x dx $$
However, the results are not valid. What mistake did I make?

Comment: $I(x)$ is undefined (divergent at $y=x$).

Comment: Your integrand is infinite along the lines $y=x$ and $y=2\pi-x$ on your region of integration, and the singularities are not integrable so the integral is divergent.

Comment: @AnneBauval What if I use the principal value to resolve the divergence? Because the divergence is also present in the double integral I, but the symmetry resolved this problem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The divergence is also present in the double integral $I$, but symmetry resolves this problem. However, when I try with Mathematica to find the value of the double integral $I$ with the property PrincipalValue->True, the result is 0, which is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

The answer is that in the case of your integral it is not allowed to change the order of integration.
$$I_1=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 x}{\cos x - \cos y} \ dy \ dx= \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos x - \cos y} \right) \cos^3x\ dx$$
$$I_2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3 x}{\cos x - \cos y} \ dx \ dy= \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3x}{\cos x - \cos y} \ dx\right)\ dy$$
Renaming in the second integral $x$ and $y$
$$I_2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3y}{\cos y - \cos x} \ dy\right)\ dx$$
It is straightforward to see that $I_1\neq I_2$

Supposing that $\,\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3y}{\cos y - \cos x} \ dy\,$ exists in the principal value sense (in fact it does)
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3y}{\cos y - \cos x} \ dy=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^2y\,(\cos y-\cos x+\cos x)}{\cos y - \cos x} \ dy$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2y\ dy+\cos x\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos y\,(\cos y-\cos x+\cos x)}{\cos y - \cos x} \ dy$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2y\ dy+\cos x\int_0^{2\pi}\cos y\ dy+\cos^2 x\int_0^{2\pi}\ dy+\cos^3 x\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos y - \cos x}$$
$$=\pi+2\pi \cos^2x+\cos^3 x\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos y - \cos x}$$
Therefore,
$$I_2=\frac1{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\pi+2\pi \cos^2x+\cos^3 x\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos y - \cos x}\right)dx$$
$$=1+\frac1{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos y - \cos x}\right)\cos^3x \ dx=1-I_1$$
$$\quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac12\Big(I_1+I_2\Big)=\frac12$$
Also, in the principal value sense
$$P.V.\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dy}{\cos x - \cos y} =2i\,P.V.\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2-2\cos x\,z+1}$$
$$=2i\,P.V.\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z-e^{ix})(z-e^{-ix})}$$
where we integrate in the positive (counter-clockwise) direction.

Adding to the contour two small half-circles (clockwise) around $z=e^{\pm ix}$ (closing the contour and leaving the poles outside the contour), and evaluating the integrals along these small arches (evaluating half-residues at $z=e^{\pm ix}$), we get zero.

It follows that $I_1=0$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I made a mistake by not adding a condition to my integral in order to disallow the change of the integration variables, such as the ordering operator (Heaviside theta function).